# Multiple pages PHP

Tags: php

I've made a script but I'm not sure how to add more pages to it.

```
if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'account.php')){
```

The above script is for the account.php page. But I also want to add the messages.php page to it.

```
if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'account.php', 'messages.php')){
```

This won't work but it's for the example.

How would I be able to do this?

Comment: call stripos multiple times. it compares two strings together. you can't magically add more strings and have it compare all of them, so call it multiple times.

Comment: Nb. Because stripos can return zero, your check will fail if the string begins with 'account.php' - use stripos () !== false